# Ubuntu 18.04.03 OVF installation - ubuntuguest login

Tags: user-management

I downloaded ubuntu ova Ubuntu Server 18.04.3 LTS and installed into a VMware. While I try to login now, it asks for ubuntuguest login. May I know the default password for this or how can I circumvent this ?

thank you
Ram

Comment: Where did you download the OVA from?  If it did not originate from Ubuntu's image sites then you should not use it because it could be compromised.  (`ubuntuguest` is ALSO not a default user for even the cloud images, so you probably need to ask wherever you got the OVA from.)